# Getting error in generate Fpdf in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I get this error

> Message: FPDF error: The document is closed

How can I solved this error? I want to generate multiple pdf.

My code is as below

```
 $ci->load->library('fpdf');
 $image = $params['savename'];
 $ci->fpdf->AddPage('A2');
 $ci->fpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
```

Comment: check https://www.google.pt/search?q=FPDF+error%3A+The+document+is+closed&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=7DL3WbzBNPOJ8QfS46LYCQ

Comment: Please add your code, no way to know like this.